# How to open angular application using ctrl+click in a new tab after deployment

Tags: angular, error-handling, iis-7.5, webdeploy

I created an angular application and deployed it on the IIS server. When I open routerLink in a new tab using ctrl+click it gives an error message

[image: Error image]

But when I open a new tab in my angular application before deploying HTML part load successfully in a new tab.

How to remove this error in the deployed angular application?

Comment: could you please share how you set the router link? did you deploy the angular application in iis as site or application? make sure you add the routing rule in iis : `<rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>`

Comment: Hi, @JalpaPanchal Thanks for your reply. I used `<a routerLink="/filename">` and I deployed this angular application as a site in IIS. And which file I use this code`<rule...>`

Comment: could you please share your detailed error message snapshot after removing sensitive information? you could add `<rule...>` code in your site root folder web.config file. make sure you have installed the URL rewrite module in iis. if not you can download and install from this link: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite